# Appending to list overwrites some properties of object in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to make a list of objects of class Sequence. But the init_seqs[i].seq is the same for all list (because init_seqs[i].seq overwrites init_seqs[i-1].seq) the other property remains the same. Given below is my code. Please let me know where am I making the mistake.

```
class Sequence(object):

def __init__(self, seq, make_span):
    self.seq=seq
    self.make_span=make_span

def getMake_span(self):
    return self.make_span

def __cmp__(self,other):
    other_makespan=other.getMake_span()
    if self.getMake_span()>other_makespan:
        return 1
    if self.getMake_span()<other_makespan:
        return -1
    else:
        return 0

class FlowShopGA(object):
....
....
def createPopultation(self):
    init_seqs=[]
    jobs=list(xrange(self.numJobs))
    for i in xrange(self.POPULATION_SIZE):
        random.shuffle(jobs)
        r = Sequence(jobs,self.calc_MakeSpan(jobs))
        init_seqs.append(r)
    sort_init_seqs = sorted(init_seqs, key=lambda Sequence: Sequence.make_span)
    self.seqs = sort_init_seqs[:self.EVOLVING_POPULATION_Size]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All instances are being passed the same object. Copy first.

```
r = Sequence(jobs[:], self.calc_MakeSpan(jobs))
```